# How to remove parenthesis in dbpedia query result in SPARQL?

Tags: database, sparql, dbpedia

I am trying to query DBpedia with SPARQL by using **CONSTRUCT** to get a list of countries and their capitals and parse the result back in Turtle format:

```
CONSTRUCT {
  ?country dbo:capital ?city.
  ?country a dbo:Country.
} WHERE {
  ?country dbo:capital ?city.
  ?country a dbo:Country
}
```

However, when there are parenthesis `()` or a `_` in the country name, the result does not use the prefixes properly.

Example:

```
dbr:Virginia  dbo:capital  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Richmond,_Virginia>
```

Is there any automated way to fix this? I don't really look forward to fixing this manually...

Comment: What do you mean by fixing? How do you handle parenthesis and how for instance do you handle the `,_`? What about other cases where there is no prefixed form possible? Do you understand why those URI can't be serialized in a prefixed form?

Comment: Moreover, why do you want to have everything prefixed? A `CONSTRUCT` query simply returns a set of RDF triples in a specified RDF serialization format. Why can't you simply work on this in the client code?

Comment: I don't understand why, but this would be really complicated. You have to (1) take the resource `r` and modify its URI `str(r)` by some function `f` which leads to a string `s = f(str(r))` and (2) this string has to be converted to a URI back by using `uri(s)`. The definition of the function `f` is up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, I don't understand why you want to do this and it remains open how you want to handle cases which aren't (can't be) prefixed in Turtle syntax. But, to give you a rough idea:

```
CONSTRUCT {
  ?country dbo:capital ?city. 
  ?country a dbo:Country.
} WHERE {
  ?country dbo:capital ?city_tmp. 
  ?country a dbo:Country
  ## here you would handle the "fix", e.g. use a regex and find some replacement
  BIND(uri(REPLACE(str(?city_tmp), ",_", "_", "i")) AS ?city)
}
```

You can see in the query that I used just a dummy regex matching `,_` and a replacement string `_`.
For example, `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Nancy,_France` will be replaced to `dbr:Nancy_France`